# Draw a stroke of a path with gradient

Tags: objective-c, performance, graphics

I'm trying to draw a stroke of Bezier Curve with linear gradient going from red to green. What I do at the moment is:

```
NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth: 1];

NSPoint startPoint = {  10, 100 };
NSPoint endPoint   = { 590, 500 };

int r1 = arc4random() % 1000;
int r2 = arc4random() % 1000;
NSPoint cp1 = { 700, -500 + r1 };
NSPoint cp2 = { -500 + r2, 700 };

[path  moveToPoint: startPoint];
[path curveToPoint: endPoint
     controlPoint1: cp1
     controlPoint2: cp2];

if (curves.count == 50) {
    [curves removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
[curves addObject:path];

int i = 0;
for (NSBezierPath * p in curves) {
    [[redColors objectAtIndex:i++] set];
    [p stroke];
}
```

And this works great, but when I convert `NSBezierPath path` to `CGPathRef myPath = [path quartzPath]` and iterate over 'CGPathRef' instead of 'NSBezierPath':

```
CGPathRef myPath = [path quartzPath];
if (curves.count == size) {
    [paths removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
[paths addObject:myPath];

CGContextRef c = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]graphicsPort];
for (int i = 0; i < paths.count; i++) {
    [self drawPath:c :[paths objectAtIndex:i]:i];
}
```

My performance drops from about 30 FPS to 5 FPS!

Here is my code for drawPath:

```
-(void) drawPath:(CGContextRef) c: (CGPathRef) myPath: (int) i {
    CGContextSaveGState(c);
    CGContextAddPath(c, myPath);
    CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(c);
    CGContextClip(c);

    //  Draw a linear gradient from top to bottom
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, cfGradients[i], start, end, 0);

    CGContextRestoreGState(c);
}
```

`redColors` and `cfGradients` are arrays storing elements with alpha from 0-1/0-255, so they don't need to be recreated at each iteration.

This performance is even much worse than in Java. Surely there must be a way to draw a stroke more efficiently without all this transitions from `NSBezierPath` to `CGPathRef`, etc.

Please help.

Comment: My solution worked fine since I was able to cache transformed path. I have a category that converts NSBezierPath -> NSBezierPath for stroke with a given line width (just like your, it worked through CGPathRef), this second cached is used to render gradients with regular NSGradient.

If you can't cache the paths, I'm afraid, there is no solution

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please post a pseudo code example of your workings? As you can see I do cache CGPathRef - [paths addObject:myPath];.

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly you're trying to do. Like, if the path is a circle, which pixels are red and which are green?